# Multiple WHERE conditions using AND => No query result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a few thousand entries. And My purpose is to select all entries from all versions that correspond to a given one. And the resulted entries must correspond exactly to the given entry.

But somehow, the SQL query does not work. The original project uses Access 2007. But I have tried also in MySQL and no success

I put here the sql query, but I also made a SQL fiddle:

```
 SELECT 
    idvalue,
    idtag,
    iddevice,
    idversion,
    idtext,
    description,
    idaccess,
    defaultvalue,
    minimumvalue,
    acceptedvalue,
    maximumvalue,
    outofrangevalue,
    iddatatypepn,
    iddatatypeopc,
    size,
    idresolution,
    idunit,
    idaccuracy,
    enumerationvalues,
    comments,
    remanentvolatile,
    storedatpn,
    storedatmain,
    `generated`,
    edittime
FROM
    SomeValues
WHERE
    idtag = 2 AND iddevice = 1
        AND idtext = 433
        AND description = 'Input voltage (AC)'
        AND idaccess = 12
        AND defaultvalue IS NULL
        AND minimumvalue =0
        AND acceptedvalue = 5300
        AND maximumvalue = 10050
        AND outofrangevalue = 11000
        AND iddatatypepn = 2
        AND iddatatypeopc = 19
        AND size = 2
        AND idresolution = 2
        AND idunit = 1
        AND idaccuracy = 2
        AND enumerationvalues IS NULL
        AND comments IS NULL
        AND remanentvolatile IS NULL
        AND storedatpn = FALSE
        AND storedatmain = FALSE
        AND `generated` = TRUE
```

Fiddle: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68ac68/2)

Can you please explain what is wrong with the sql query?
The result should be those 3 entries from the fiddle table.

And yes, I must use all the conditions from the "Where" clause, since the entries can match 90% but also have small differences

Comment: What problem you are facing actually ? MySQL must has give you an error message. Or this isn't giving you your desired result ?

Comment: I'm not going to bother checking this, because 95% chance that your `WHERE` clause simply does not match either of the 2 records in your table.  Check your logic.

Comment: Thank you... I will try to look to see if this happens. But I have checked many times.
As I said, I used Access initially, but I cannot ,make a fiddle for that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem in line:

```
AND description = 'Input voltage (AC)'
```

change it to:

```
AND description = '"Input voltage (AC)"'
```

and everything will works.

Problem lies in the fact that you searched for text **Input voltage (AC)** instead of **"Input voltage (AC)"** (how is stated in column `description`).